# Returning 2 result sets from a sproc that has a CTE into a DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, common-table-expression

My stored proc looks like:

```
WITH MYCTE(...)
AS
(
..
)


SELECT cte.*
FROM MYCTE cte

SELECT *
FROM table1
  INNER JOIN MYCTE ...
```

So things were working fine with a single result set, I added the last SELECT statement to my sproc and now I get an error saying it doesn't know what MYCTE is.

Why am I not allowed to do this?

Assuming it works somehow (with your advice), do I have to change my dataset.fill call to bring back 2 result sets (tables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to return a single result set?  Then you'll have to do a UNION or else use a temp table or table variable to combine them.

But to answer the question:  CTEs are only good for a single SELECT (or UPDATE, DELETE, etc.)  They're actually part of the SELECT statement.  So when you do the second select, it has no idea what MYCTE is supposed to be.

Comment: Makes sense now.  But is there a way to seperate and start a new select and then have my dataset put that other select in another table (in the same sproc)?

Comment: Yes; in fact, that's the default behavior, or used to be.  (Obviously you have to use an overload of Fill that doesn't specify a particular table name.)  Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: how can I store the result of the cte into a table variable?  it complains if i define the table variable above the cte code.

Comment: @codecompleting  What exactly is its complaint?  What error message is it showing you?  (And did you end the declaration with a semicolon?  A statement with a CTE needs to either be the first statement or for the previous statement to end with a ";")